# MongoDB querying date

Tags: php, mongodb

Querying with `$gt` is not working as expected if the date's are same. It's more like `$gte`.

But if I add 1 second to query param then it works.

Here is the sample query;

I have a document which it's `creation_date`  `1367414837` timestamp.

```
db.collection.find({creation_date : {'$gt' : new Date(1367414837000)}});
```

This query matches with the document which date's `1367414837`
If i increment the query timestamp just one like `1367414838`. it works expected.

Im using mongo console but i have same problem in php with `MongoDate`

edit: output of query

```
db.collection.findOne({creation_date : {'$gt' : new Date(1367414837000)}});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5181183543c51695ce000000"),
    "action" : {
        "type" : "comment",
        "comment" : {
            "id" : 74,
            "post_id" : "174",
            "owner_id" : "5",
            "text" : "ne diyeyim lae :D",
            "creation_date" : "2013-05-01 16:27:17"
        }
    },
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2013-05-01T13:27:17.336Z"),
    "owner" : {
        "id" : "5",
        "username" : "tylerdurden"
    }
}
```

edit2: problem is php extension of mongo. it's documented " any precision beyond milliseconds will be lost when the document is sent to/from the database."
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php

I incremented query param one second as a turnaround solution.

Comment: can you show the output of that find?  what is the type of creation_date?  what's the output of the above find (change find to findOne so that only one document is returned).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I edited question with output.

Comment: so it looks like the dates are not the same - they differ in milliseconds component...

Comment: ohh i see, thank you for the notify. but i couldnt expect it but it looks like problem is with php MongoDate object. It loses milliseconds part of the date.

Comment: If your second edit solved the problem for you, you may want to post it as an answer to the question instead.  [There's nothing wrong with answering your own questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 3):

[Dates in BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) are UNIX dates equal to milliseconds since epoch; they're accurate down to the millisecond.  If the times you're inserting (and trying to match against) are accurate to the millisecond level, the element you're trying to match is possibly just a few milliseconds later than the timestamp you're querying, and `$gt` is likely working as expected.  (2013-05-01T13:27:17.001Z is indeed later than 2013-05-01T13:27:17Z, for example.)

Comment: I see but what i query is actually date i output from collection. I get date from mongo and pass it to query function as param. So same date comparision with '$gt' shouln't match with anyone, right?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the value of "creation_date" in your document with the nested "creation_date" in the action.comment subdocument.  It looks like the value in your subdocument is only accurate to the whole second, which is why you expect "$gt" to not return this document, despite the fact that its value for "creation_date" in the main document is 336 ms later.  If you really want to query on the date in the subdocument, do a find against {"action.comment.creation_date" : {"$gt", new Date(TIMESTAMP_GOES_HERE)}}.

Comment: actually i want to query on parent document so query is correct. but as you mentioned and Asya mentioned there is time difference which i couldnt expect. I'm looking php MongoDate object for the problem. It looks like MongoDate is not accurate..